# Android: AlarmManager setExact() not firing event in Android 8

Tags: android

I have an Android implementation in which I have to schedule notifications in the long term, I create the PendingIntent and use [AlarmManager#setExact()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method to do it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BirthdayReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra(BirthdayReceiver.INTENT_WHO, contact.getName());

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        mContext, id, intent, 0);

mAlarmManager.setExact(
        AlarmManager.RTC,
        notificationCalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        pendingIntent);
```

I've checked the time passed to setExact() method, if it's a short time (minutes, few hours) then the notification appears correctly.

But if I set a notification to fire, let's say the next day at 12:00 it doesn't work.

I am using an Android 8 device to test it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like flag is not specified.
Could you try it with [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) .

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        mContext, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Also, in order to confirm if your PendingIntent is still available in the system, you can use [FLAG_NO_CREATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_NO_CREATE).

```
PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, id,
          intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

if broadcastIntent returns null then the PendingIntent is not avaialble (possibly cancelled) in the system.

As per the documentation of [setexact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> This method is like set(int, long, PendingIntent), but does not permit
>   the OS to adjust the delivery time. The alarm will be delivered as
>   nearly as possible to the requested trigger time.

So you may not expect the alarm to be triggered immediately.

> Note: only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time
>   delivery (such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time) should
>   be scheduled as exact. Applications are strongly discouraged from
>   using exact alarms unnecessarily as they reduce the OS's ability to
>   minimize battery use.

So you can really consider whether you really need to call this API or not

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but the alarm NEVER fires. It is ok for me if it has a delay of minutes..even hours, but the problem is that the event is lost forever.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @svprdga updated the answer with a way to know if the pendingintent still exists in the system. Hope it helps you.